# Exract a Substring from a String within a Range

Tags: vba, excel

I want to search a range for a string, then extract a substring from the string. The format of the string is xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx, where the x's may be letters or numbers. I am trying to identify the substring in reference to the "-". This code returns the "type mismatch" error on the line before End If.

```
For m = 7 To 16
    If InStr(EIRPBudget.Cells(m, 12), "-") Then
        FilterDescrip = EIRPBudget.Cells(m, 12)
        EIRPSummary.Range("V" & i + 5) = Split(FilterDescrip, "-")(0)
    End If
Next
```

Any assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: I've answered *why* the type mismatch occurs, but I don't know *what* the "i = 5" is supposed to be doing. Or is it a typo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Type Mismatch` is caused by this part: `EIRPSummary.Range("V" & i = 5)` which is evaluated as "VFALSE" if `i` isn't 5 and "VTRUE" if it is...

**UPDATE**

I don't think you can get away with all-VBA without a loop, since you need to be iterating individual cells in a range. However you can modify your code to only evaluate the cell value once per iteration... but I don't think there's going to be a huge impact over the small number of iterations you're doing:

```
Dim cellValue As String
For m = 7 To 16
    cellValue = EIRPBudget.Cells(m, 12)
    If InStr(cellValue, "-") Then _
        EIRPSummary.Range("V" & i + 5) = Split(cellValue, "-")(0)
Next
```

Alternatively, if you can add another column in your worksheet, `=LEFT([A1],FIND("-",[A1])-1)` (where [A1] is the cell with "xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx") gives you just that: the *n* left-most characters up to the position of the first occurrence of "-", excluding that character.

Comment: I feel stupid. You caught a typo. The "=" should be a "+" and now it works fine. Thanks, pal. Maybe someone can explain a more efficient alternative that does not require a loop.

Comment: @Max I think I've found a loopless way.. which happens to be also codeless :)

Comment: I like both implemenations. Thanks for taking the time.